# Heroku db:push throws exception in the middle of the operation

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to execute the following command on my Heroku app:

```
heroku db:push postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/db_name
```

I successful used the same command a lot of times in the past three months but today it stopped working. It seems like it stopped working as soon as it reached 5MB in size (now it's about 8MB big). The thing is that I now started paying for the shared database so I should be allowed to have 20GB space.

This is the command output:

```
> heroku db:push postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/db_name --account java
Loaded Taps v0.3.23
Warning: Data in the app 'my-test-app' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.

 !    WARNING: Potentially Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: my-test-app
 !    To proceed, type "my-test-app" or re-run this command with --confirm my-test-app

> my-test-app
Sending schema
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:46
Sending indexes
test_gift_rec: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:01
test_person:   100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:01
Sending data
14 tables, 114 records
test_bonus_aw: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
test_money_tr: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
test_friendsh: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
test_friendsh: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
test_gift_rec: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
test_group:    100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
test_country:  100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
test_user_is_: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
test_gift:     100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
test_user_has:   0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--
Saving session to push_201204301144.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for nil:NilClass
["/app/lib/taps/data_stream.rb:183:in `parse_json'", "/app/lib/taps/server.rb:89:in `block in <class:Server>'","/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/satra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'", "/app/.bune/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `instance_eval'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:5:in `route_eval'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:500:in `block (2 levels) in route!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `catch'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `block in route!, "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `each'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/baseb:476:in `route!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:601:in `dispatch!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinat-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `block in call!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `instance_eval'", "/appbundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `block in invoke'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/ba.rb:566:in `catch'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `invoke'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchroze'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'", "/home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:in `call'", "/homheroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:15:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `block in call'", "/app/.bundleems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `each'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'", "/he/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:77:in `call'", "/app/.bundle/gems/by/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:76:in `block in pre_process'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb::in `catch'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `pre_process'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'","/app/.bundle/ms/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in`run_machine'","/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine0.12.10/lib/eventchine.rb:256:in `run'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tn-1.2.7/lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'", "/app/.ndle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:143: `run!'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'", "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'", "/a/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'"]
```

Running on Windows 7.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the pgbackups addon if you're not changing the DB between local and production.

It is more reliable and usually faster than a db:push/db:pull.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

Comment: Right, thank you for this, @JohnBeynon. It has solved my problem! The thing is that this is just a workaround, do you think my original problem is due to a Heroku bug?

Comment: db:push functionality is via the TAPS gem which is not managed by Heroku - it could be something as simple as a rogue character in your DB that Taps is unable to read. Does it does the same thing each time? It could have just been a glitch.

Comment: There are two particular tables having problems in the push.. If I push the DB with the argument `--exclude table1,table2` and then I push these two tables separately (`--tables table1` and `--tables table2`), it works fine. I guess it's a TAPS bug, then...